# How to create swipeable horizontal div larger than the view?

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, gesture

I'm creating a web app and am trying to add a div container with a swipe gesture.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve. Browser view and the remaining divs that are not visible until they're swiped into the view]

The cards will by in view one by one. can be swiped left or right.

I know this is very much possible by simply using overflow:hidden; but is there a more conventional, practical, or purposeful way of doing this?

Comment: You can use the touch moves event. Depending on the change in the x axis, you can tell it to swipe left or swipe right.

Comment: There are approximately 10,555,000,000 images sliders and carousel examples in the world to draw from. Have you checked any of those out as starting points for your project?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes I have. Owl Carousel seems to be like a pretty stable and good option. But I am trying to build this one on my own without a library

Comment: I didn't suggest you use a library - if you like Owl then you have a reference you can use to answer the type of question you've asked here. Owl has solved this problem already. Go [here](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/4eedccac4ea061931162a86e3f268332c16a1ad0/src/js/owl.carousel.js) and use your browser search for the term `touch`